# Django. Tweet image saved on ImageField

Tags: python, django, twitter, tweepy

I want to tweet an image saved on a model's `ImageField`. I'm using `tweepy`, but I'm open to anything that works.

This is what I've tried:

**First:**

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
api.update_with_media(filename=model_object.image.name, status=text, file=model_object.image)
```

> error: TweepError: Invalid file type for image: None

**Then:**

```
from PIL import Image

api = tweepy.API(auth)
image_file = Image.open(model_object.image)
api.update_with_media(filename=model_object.image.name, status=text, file=image_file)
```

> 219, in update_with_media
>       headers, post_data = API._pack_image(filename, 3072, form_field='media[]', f=f)   File
>   "/home/alejandro/Proyectos/criptohisoka/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/api.py",
>   line 1311, in _pack_image
>       f.seek(0, 2)  # Seek to end of file TypeError: seek() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

**Finally:**

```
from PIL import Image
from StringIO import StringIO

api = tweepy.API(auth)
image_file = Image.open(model_object.image)
stringio_obj = StringIO()
image_file.save(stringio_obj, format="JPEG")
api.update_with_media(filename=model_object.image.name, status=text, file=stringio_obj)
```

> TweepError: Invalid file type for image: None

I'm not sure what the `update_with_media` method expects as a file. Here is   the relevant`tweepy` [source code](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py) and here are the [docs](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.update_with_media).

Comment: It looks like it's looking for a File object, so your 2nd example should work. Could you expand on the stacktrace with the TypeError? It looks like the problem may not lie with the actual call.

Comment: deprecated https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update_with_media

Comment: @lonewaft Just added some more traceback ... but there ain't much to add. Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `upload_with_media` endpoint has been deprecated, see [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update_with_media), I'm going to suggest you to use the following method:

Use the absolute path to the file

```
media_ids = api.media_upload(filename=model_object.image.file.name)
```

Twitter API will respond with a long integer cached in the `media_ids` variable.

Finally, use the `update_status` endpoint:

```
params = {'status': 'chop chop chop', 'media_ids': [media_ids.media_id_string]}
response = api.update_status(**params)
```

For reference, see the method definitions in tweepy, and their correspondence in Twitter api:

1. [Tweepy: media_upload](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py#L196)
2. [Tweepy: update_status](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py#L178)
3. [Twitter API: update endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update)
4. [Twitter API: media_upload endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload)

Comment: Thanks for the answer man. There is one error though: `params = {'status': 'chop chop chop', 'media_ids': [media_ids]}` should be `params = {'status': 'chop chop chop', 'media_ids': [media_ids.media_id_string]}` . I changed `media_ids` to `media_ids.media_id_string` and it worked. Please edit your answer, I'll accept it then. Cheers.

Comment: Good catch, and glad to help @alejoss